# Error message on return statement.

Tags: java

I am writing one method which having `int` prototype. But the method is showing error in editor by saying that **Add return statement** where return statement is already present. When I am adding another return it is working fine. I am writing in eclipse.

Here is my code :

```
private static int nextPrime(int n) {
        if(n % 2 == 0)
            n++;
        for(; !isPrime(n); n+=2)

        return n;
        return n;
    }
```

What is going wrong here. Thanks for help.

Comment: Every exit path needs to return int. You might never enter the 'for' cycle (which had the only return before). So if you don't enter the 'for' you don't have a return value and you must always have one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that your `for` loop has no body.  Try giving it one:

```
private static int nextPrime(int n) {
    if(n % 2 == 0)
        n++;
    for(; !isPrime(n); n+=2) { }

    return n;
}
```

But really I think a `for` loop is the wrong kind of loop for this.  Instead, you might want to use a `while` loop:

```
private static int nextPrime(int n) {
    if (n % 2 == 0)
        n++;

    while (!isPrime(n)) {
        n += 2;
    }

    return n;
}
```

Comment: Yes that is working... I am new so I am practicing from here http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-implement-hash-tables/ and there something missing.

Answer (score 3):

The first `return` is in the scope of the loop, then the compiler force you to put one at the end of the function as you must ensure that on every path a return is made, alas the compiler cannot prove by itself that you always enter the loop...

It seems that your loop lack of a body...

Comment: Yes even I also got the same. Thanks